# Git rewrite history using filter-branch 'Permission denied'

Tags: git, url-rewriting, permission-denied, git-rewrite-history

When I try to slim my repo using command:

```
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter 'rm -rf `/Volumes/RamDisk/FF/large_files.txt | cut -d " " -f 2` ' --prune-empty master
```

I get the output in my console:

```
Rewrite 072caf825338a50130903528862caa12cebd1c87 (1/3214)/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: line 318: /Volumes/RamDisk/FF/large_files.txt: Permission denied
Rewrite 2e7c35b1dd73b2b2ceb010a3cd98ad6906b0716e (2/3214)/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: line 318: /Volumes/RamDisk/FF/large_files.txt: Permission denied...
```

large_files.txt is just text file with list of files to remove, I own it and have all permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 luka  staff   6983  3 Oct 23:00 large_files.txt
```

I made sure .git-rewrite is not in the repo (deleted) and force flag does not help?

What permissions exactly is this about? 
File system permissions, Git remote permissions or other? 
It is my repo, I have full access to it, tried with sudo and,  nothing helps.
BTW: large_files.txt is just text file with list of files to remove,

Can you help me udnerstand what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know the equivalent of strace, anything like it should show you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: possibly some files do not exist at particular commit; in my case I needed to remove a directory and had to pass "if" into a filter command: ```git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -e DIR ];then rm -rf DIR ; fi' HEAD```

Comment: actually not sure about adding "if" so take my advice with a grain of salt

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute `large_files.txt` (notice what's inside the `` ` `` characters in your argument to `--tree-filter`).  The shell, perhaps confusingly, says "Permission denied" when you try to execute a file that is not executable (even if you optimistically set its permissions to `a+x`).  You probably meant to have a `cat` in there somewhere, no?

By the way, it's probably safer to use `xargs` than to just expand that in the arguments to `rm`.  For example:

```
cut -d " " -f 2 /Volumes/RamDisk/FF/large_files.txt | xargs rm -rf
```